# Did Russian government employ state-sponsored assassins under Russian Empire?

Tags: russia, government, assassination

Did Russian government employ state-sponsored assassins under Russian Empire during 1800-1917?
I know, killings of many figures disliked by the Tsar were arranged in the forms of staged duels, but what about assassinations?

Note: executions do not count, open shootings of rioters do nor count. I am asking about secret killings by order of the government of specific people (called by name).

Comment: Why should the Russian Empire be the *one* government *without* spies, intelligence operatives, counterterrorists, you-name-them?

Comment: @DevSolar I am asking about historical facts. I am not asking about police, riot control, etc. I am asking specifically about assassinations by order of certain figures.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Who were these "many figures" whose deaths were arranged in the form of duels? Please, provide a reference to this claim. (If you meant Pushkin as an example, then this claim ahistorical.)

Comment: What area of Russian history are you thinking about?  There's a huge difference between how things worked during the reign of Ivan the Terrible versus Nicholas II

Comment: @Anixx: I wanted to make you aware that one person's counterterrorist operative is another person's assassin. One person's intelligence agent is another person's assassin. One person's police officer in distress is another person's assassin. The definition of "assassin" is pretty loose, and opinion-based. All that aside, again, it would be quite strange if the Tsar's regime would have been the *one* government in history that *didn't* make use of politically motivated killings. All others did...

Comment: @GorttheRobot 1800-1917

Comment: @DevSolar well, executions do not count, open shootings of rioters do nor count. I asked about secret killings by order of the government of specific people (called by name).

Comment: @Anixx Can you edit those dates into the question?

Comment: please move the comm into the question

Comment: I can think of the case of major Sinkler (who was a messenger between Sweden and Turkey and was killed by Russian assassins in Poland to prevent the then ongoing effort to coordinate France-Sweden-Turkey coalition against Russia), but it's from 1738

Comment: Had you widened your time frame I would've posted an answer

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov and, I mostly meant Russian subjects or those who lived in Russia (e.g, the government could arrest them, but chose to murder).

Comment: Imperial government didn't employ such policy against its own subject on Russian territory. Abroad, possibly yes, like other governments did and do to this day.  There were assassinations in Russia (even against monarchs) but strictly legally they were not done by the order of Imperial government . More like cliques competing against each other. Usually, revolutionaries were arrested and sometimes executed after the trial, but not killed in secret.